# How to specify android:textColor on pressed ListItem?

Tags: android, android-layout

My listitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/f_w" android:layout_height="60sp" android:padding="0sp">
<TextView android:id="@+id/con_name"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    style="@style/w_w" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/con_time"
    android:textSize="13sp" 
    android:textColor="#565"
    style="@style/w_w" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, I want to specify textColor of my textviews on item pressed. I'm using custom listview via baseadapter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView disabling color-changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424946/android-textview-disabling-color-changing)

Comment: @userSeven7s no, vice verse: I wan't to create color changing (I didn't have it, thanks to Ole).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a selector for your TextView text color.

res/color/list_item_text_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/focused_color" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/pressed_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color" />
</selector>
```

res/layout/listitem.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/con_name"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_text_color_selector"
    style="@style/w_w" />
```

If you want this to apply to both TextViews, you can add it in @style/w_w and remove the android:textColor part from your TextView.

```
<style name="w_w">
    ...
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_text_color_selector</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: No, I don't want to apply it to both TextViews. Default (not pressed/selected) colors are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the list view onItemClickListner and in that set this for the item `myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));`

Comment: May I ask you an example with onItemClickListener?

Comment: Refer this tutorial. and check for the code  `lv.setOnItemClickListener` http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If your Activity extends ListActivity you can change the color of any element of the listitem.xml just overriding:

```
@Override  
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    TextView tv = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.con_name);
    tv.setTextColor(R.color.red);
}
```